# Color of inactive geometry in texture paint mode

Tags: texture-painting

How to change the color (or alpha fade) of unmasked geometry in texture paint mode.

[image]

Comment: I'm not finding anything in the user preferences in themes that corresponds to this. I tried everything with an alpha value so far and nothing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is it.